# SQL - A table with two same column names

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with user_id and entitlement where entitlement can be full game or demo, so a given user_id could have up to two rows if the user played both the full game and demo.

I did a join to get a table with two columns that gives me info on whether or not a user who has played the full game has played the demo. The first column gives me all the IDs of players who has played the full game, while the second column will repeat the ID if the player has played the demo, or NULL if he/she hasn't.

```
select * from 
(
 (select e.user_id 
    from table1 e 
    where entitlement = 'fullgame') fg
 left join
 (select e.user_id 
    from table1 e 
    where entitlement = 'demo') demo
 on fg.user_id = demo.user_id 
)
```

My problem is now when I'm trying to join this table to tables with other information (age, country), Teradata SQL Assistant gives me an error saying there are two columns of the same name, i.e. user_id

How can I write my query to distinguish between the two columns. Do I have to somehow rename one of the columns first?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias like so:

```
select * from 
(
 (select e.user_id as userid1
    from table1 e 
    where entitlement = 'fullgame') fg
 left join
 (select e.user_id as userid2
    from table1 e 
    where entitlement = 'demo') demo
 on fg.userid1 = demo.userid2 
)
```

You can use the `as` keyword if you like or you can just write it like this `e.user_id userid1`, both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias the field name like this

```
 Select e.user_id fullgameuserid
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question as been answered (i.e., use `as`), your query seems overly complicated.  There is no reason to have subqueries for the joins:

```
select f.user_id, d.user_id as demo_user_id
from table1 f left join
     table1 d
     on f.user_id = d.user_id and
        d.entitlement = 'demo'
where f.entitlement = 'fullgame';
```

I also think that having a flag for the second column might better fit with what you want to accomplish:

```
select f.user_id,
       (case when d.user_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as DemoFlag
```